# Long render times in Cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

So previously I have been making small animations in Blender 2.7. I wasn't around for the 2.8 update and I found I had to relearn a lot of key binds and stuff like that. However, loading an old project that I worked on in 2.7, I found that it takes a lot longer to render. I used to have a 1080p 200 sample image render in 2-3 minutes. Now 20 samples at 720p take just as long, and I did not change anything in my project or PC. Even a 1 sample image takes 10 seconds. I am still using Cycles instead of Eevee but switching to Eevee takes just as long. Is it something I'm doing?

**EDIT** - I did upgrade my PC a little, but I switched from an 8GB kit of Memory to a 16GB kit. I am going to switch from a i3 to a Ryzen 7 in the future, and I have a GTX 1050ti.

Comment: Have you controlled for _Resolution %_? After 2.8, it became _100%_ by default, whereas in 2.7x and before it used to be _50%_. You can find it in the _Dimensions_ section of the _Output Properties_ tab.

Comment: @impresso That certainly did help, thanks! I'm still getting render times more than twice as long as before but that did help and worst case scenario is I'll deal with it.

Comment: It's still rather weird; I think you should try putting it to the test. [Here](https://www.blender.org/download/previous-versions/) you can download the 2.7x version you used to work on and directly compare its performance with the current release's.